# Ruby on Rails Michael Hartl turorial. Failing test Chapter 9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I run

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"
```

Terminal returns:

```
sis-macbook-pro:sample_app Lagaspi$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"
/Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load': /Users/Lagaspi/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

I really do not know how to tackle this problem, but here is my  spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { visit user_path(user) }

describe "signup" do
before { visit signup_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end

describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
it "should not create a user" do
expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  before do
fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
end

it "should create a user" do
  expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
end

 describe "after saving the user" do
before { click_button submit }
it { should have_link('Sign out') }
  end
describe "edit" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

describe "page" do
  it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
end

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Save changes" }

  it { should have_content('error') }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If this is the exact code then you're missing two more `end` at the bottom. Add that and try again.

I cut/pasted your code into vim and did auto-indent to find the culprit.

**Update:**

Plus, your original error says `missing end`. The first one is on `line 66` while the next error you listed here in the comments says `line 67`. These are exactly the lines where your `end` are missing.

Comment: Actually missing two `ends` at the end

Comment: /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load': /Users/Lagaspi/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:67: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

Comment: I've checked this: add two `end` keywords at the end of the file and I don't get a syntax error any more.